Unable to sign-in on Canvas app embeded in iframe
We have a canvas app embedded in an iframe.  When prompted to sign-in, clicking on the sign-in button, a "App not working" error message is shown.  Running the app via a direct link works.
Please advise.

You may want to read [ask]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
